# rPi3 Access Point and Ubuntu artful 17.10

Tags: networking, wireless, ubuntu

I just configured the raspbian as an AP. The Wi-Fi connection works well on windows and android, but when I try to connect from Ubuntu, it enters but does not have an internet connection:
[image: wifi icon connected, no internet]

In the ubuntu computer, I have tried:

- Disable IPv6.
- Put IPv4 as manual, automatic or only local network.
- Try with another ubuntu 17.10 laptop.
- Verify if I have IP: Yes I have:[image: ifconfig result]

Always obtaining the same results.
Suggestions?

Comment: According to your question, the RPi works fine. The problem seems to be with Ubuntu.

Comment: The problem was solved editing, in raspbian, the file `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`

adding
        `option domain-name "local";` and 
        `option domain-name-servers 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220;`
to the subnet configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS problem. 
The solution was add a custom dns in the connection options.